# How to dynamically initialize the size of an array of linked lists java

Tags: java, generics, casting, linked-list, hashtable

I have a constructor that specifies how large my array of linked lists should be but I am having troubles initializing the size of the array. This is what I'm trying but I get an error whenever I try initializing the array:

// constructor

```
MyConstruct(int initSize){
    hashTable = (LinkedList<T>[]) new Object[initSize];
}
```

ERROR:
java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.LinkedList;

How do I create an array of linked lists in which I could do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < hashTable.size(); i++){
    hashTable[i].add(i + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This *would* work:](http://ideone.com/tW1JHK)

```
MyConstruct(int initSize){
    hashTable = new LinkedList[initSize];
}
```

but really, just use a list of lists!

```
MyConstruct(int initSize){
    hashTable = new LinkedList<LinkedList<T>>();
}
```

Comment: or to avoid raw types: `hashTable = (LinkedList<T>[])new LinkedList<?>[initSize];`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change an array to list, you can do it like this:
    Arrays.asList(array)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If `T` is a generic parameter in your class `MyConstruct<T>`, then you will have problems with creating an array of `LinkedList<T>`.  Type erasure will make this a `LinkedList[]` at runtime, and there is no good way to add code to check that one adds the right kind of `LinkedList` to the array.

Don't mix up arrays and generics.  Instead, use a `List<LinkedList<T>>` instead. That should work fine.  However, what is the purpose of your list of linked lists? Would a `MultiMap`, say from Google Guava, serve better?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
MyConstruct(int initSize){
    hashTable = new LinkedList[initSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < initSize; i++) {
        hashTable[i] = new LinkedList();
    }
}
```